# The stepUp method increases value by step rather than by 1

Tags: javascript, html

I've noticed that despite [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_number_stepup.asp), `stepUp()` do use `step` property to increase input value if no value passed to the method. Tested on latest Chrome, Opera, Firefox. The following example alerts `3.15`.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('pi');
input.stepUp();
alert(input.value);
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" value="3.14" id="pi">
```

Is it a non-documented feature?

Comment: [The spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) says `void stepUp(optional long n = 1);`, indicating the default should be `1` if no parameter is passed (it also details the [algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-stepup)). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) and [WPD](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/HTMLInputElement/stepUp) don't seem to document the `stepUp` method in detail. There is an [open Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=835773) related to `stepUp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should refer to [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) instead of w3schools. On the link you posted it is not clear that `number` in `stepUp(number)` is optional and set to 1 if not present (Scroll down to DOM Interface).

```
void stepUp(optional long n = 1);
```

Also it's not clear that `number` has to be multiplied by step to get the final `delta`. ([ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-stepup))

> 6.[...] Otherwise (value subtracted from the step base is an integral multiple of the allowed value step), run the following substeps:
>
> 1. Let n be the argument.
> 2. Let delta be the allowed value step multiplied by n.
> 3. If the method invoked was the stepDown() method, negate delta.
> 4. Let value be the result of adding delta to value.

In you example since `number` in `stepUp(number)` is not present default 1 is taken and multiplied by step 0.1 to get `delta`

Comment: Another good source of information is MDN. W3C is the most accurate by definition, but it can be a bit hard to digest.

Comment: Thank you, now it is clear, that the parameter passed is a number of steps, not `delta`.